# Why am I getting the error "parameter pack 'F' must be at the end of the template parameter list"

Tags: c++

I have code that uses a variadic template and I'm trying to understand where to put the ellipsis. In the below code I put them, like the error says, at the *end* of the template parameter list. But I still get errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
template <typename T> struct S {

    void operator << (const T &) {}

};

template <template <typename, typename...> class ... F, typename T = int>
struct N : S<F<T>> ... {};
```

> `prog.cpp:10:82: error: parameter pack 'F' must be at the end of the template parameter list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have another parameter, `T`, at the end of the list after `F`. As the error message says, the variadic pack must come at the end. Unfortunately, that makes it awkward to have both variadic and defaulted parameters in the same template.