# Variadic template constructor with multiple parameters packs

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831501/how-can-i-have-multiple-parameter-packs-in-a-variadic-template?noredirect=1&lq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200391/multiple-variadic-parameter-pack-for-template-class), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766112/c11-i-can-go-from-multiple-args-to-tuple-but-can-i-go-from-tuple-to-multiple) and many others... but none of these posts answers or is applicable to my specific problem.

I have a struct `X` with a variadic template constructor:

```
struct X
{
    template<typename... T>
    X(T... t)   { /*...*/ }
};
```

And I have a structure `Y` that contains two objects of type `X`. I would like to define a template constructor for `Y`, allowing to properly initialize both members of type `X` with distinct parameters list, ie something that looks like the following code (which obviously does not work):

```
struct Y
{
    template<typename... U, typename... V>
    Y(U&&... u, V&&... v)                                // this does not work
        : x1(std::forward(u)...), x2(std::forward(v)...) // this is was I need to do
        {}

    X x1, x2;
};
```

How could I do that, using wrappers, tuples or any suitable metaprogramming machinery ? A C++14 solution is acceptable.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: I am asking for C++14 ; the question you linked may be a suitable solution to my problem but it is 2 years old ! maybe there is a better one using C++14.

Comment: I'm not so sure that c++14 changed much about the unpacking of VTPs, but well ...

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: you are not sure ? I am quite sure C++14 added some new interesting features for unpacking tuples...

Comment: Oh, you re-tagged the question now, so I couldn't reopen it single handedly, sorry. But that gives a chance that re-opening is at least confirmed by 4 others. Gave you an upvote, to attract more reviewers.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Maybe you should consider taking more time before flagging a question. In the last 4 hours, 2 over 3 flagged questions in the C++ tag are flagged by you. Don't take offense, just think about it.

Comment: Well, most of the time I'm right about it (and it were even more). Yours was an unfortunate incident, so I'm actually sorry as mentioned.

Comment: @Barry Any opinion at this case? I just duped trusting nathan, but neither me or he were actually sure about that dupe.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I voted to reopen as I kind of think the question and the answers are confusing at best.

Comment: @Barry It was that unfortunate removal of the c++ tag then, well I already apologized for that premature closing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bog-standard `index_sequence` trick.

```
struct Y
{
private:
    template<typename... U, typename... V,
             std::size_t... UIs, std::size_t... VIs>
    Y(std::tuple<U...>&& u, std::tuple<V...>&& v,
      std::index_sequence<UIs...>, std::index_sequence<VIs...>)
        : x1(std::get<UIs>(std::move(u))...), 
          x1(std::get<VIs>(std::move(v))...)  
        {}
public:
    template<typename... U, typename... V>
    Y(std::tuple<U...> u, std::tuple<V...> v)
        : Y(std::move(u), std::move(v),
            std::index_sequence_for<U...>{},
            std::index_sequence_for<V...>{})
        {}

    X x1, x2;
};
```

In C++17, just use [`make_from_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/make_from_tuple):

```
struct Y
{
public:
    template<typename... U, typename... V>
    Y(std::tuple<U...> u, std::tuple<V...> v)
        : x1(std::make_from_tuple<X>(std::move(u))),
          x2(std::make_from_tuple<X>(std::move(v)))
        {}

    X x1, x2;
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your trick works well... unless I want to pass references to inner objects `x1` & `x2`; (I tried using `std::forward_as_tuple()` but this did not work.) Is there any way to modify your code so that it can work with tuples of references ? (I updated my question in order to show the perfect forwarding I need.)

Comment: There shouldn't be a need for any modification.

Comment: That's right ! I made mistake on the parameters list. Your trick works perfectly well for references too. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Using a tuple is a big overhead, since it already require from X to be moveable/copyable, you can use that constraint directly, and get the most readable code ever:

```
struct Y
{
    Y(X && _x1, X && _x2)                        
        : x1(std::move(_x1)), x2(std::move(_x2)) 
        {}

    X x1, x2;
};
```

And in code just write:

```
Y y(X(args_x1...), X(args_x2...));
```

Or if X has implicit constructor:

```
Y y({args_x1...}, {args_x2...});
```

[SampleCode](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3cd78cc78d3d2d5)

The more interesting problem is, what if X is not moveable/copyable, but this is out of the scope ;)