# partial class template specialization with parameter pack not in last position

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

The following code comes from [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34941816/12291), and it works. I tested it with recent versions of GCC, Clang, ICC and MSVC. But I don't understand which part of the standard allows this kind of construction, could you please help?

```
template<class F, class Alloc> class C; //undefined
template<class T, class... Args, class Alloc>
class C<T(Args...), Alloc> {
    // implementation
};
```

The C++ standard provides constraints on how parameter packs can be used in primary class templates, but I can't figure out how these apply to partial specializations.

So my question is: where are the rules of placement for parameter packs in the context of partial template specialization defined in the C++ standard?

Comment: What's your actual question? How does partial specialization work?

Comment: You mean like [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.class.spec#8)?

Comment: Thanks, that looks indeed like right on topic. But then it says "If an argument is a pack expansion ([temp.variadic]), it shall be the last argument in the template argument list." which seems to contradict the example, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Drealmer `T(Args...)` is not a pack expansion argument. `Args...` would have been a pack expansion argument

Comment: alright, this is starting to make sense, thanks guys! but then does this say something about the placement of parameter packs inside the parameter list of a specialization? (since the part about the argument list is indeed not a problem)

Answer (score 1):

While not a formal and technically correct way of understanding how partial specialization works *(check out [the cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) for a more technical explanation)*, you can think of the code snippet you posted in terms of "pattern matching" *(just as an **intuition**)*:

```
// `C` is a template class that takes two types as template parameters.
template<class F, class Alloc> class C; 

// I'm going to specialize `C` so that:
// * The first type will be a function signature type, where the return
//   type is going to be matched by `T` and the argument types will be 
//   matched by `Args...`.
// * The second type will be an user-provided `Alloc` typename.
template<class T, class... Args, class Alloc>
class C<T(Args...), Alloc> { /* ... */ };
```

Let's say I instantiate `C` like this:

```
using My_C = C<int(float, char), std::allocator<int>>;
My_C c;
```

Very roughly speaking, `My_C` will *"match"* the `C<T(Args...), Alloc>` partial template specialization as follows:

```
int ( float, char )     std::allocator<int>
^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 T  (    Args...  )           Alloc
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         F                    Alloc
```

`int` is *"matched"* by `T`, and `float, char` are *"matched"* by `Args...`. There's no reason why `Args...` should be restricted to be the last template parameter of `C`.

As you can see, it is not required for the `Args...` parameter pack to be the last template argument, as we're just using it to "provide a name" for the argument type list in the passed function signature.

Comment: Mind explaining the downvote? I interpreted the question as *"I thought that parameter packs need to be at the end of parameter lists and I do not understand why this code works"*, and tried to give a non-formal interpretation of the role of `Args...` in the posted code snippet.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote either, it isn't mine.

Comment: We don't really have "pattern matching" in C++. Picking a partial specialization involves template deduction and partial ordering.

Comment: @Barry: I am aware of that, I used the "pattern matching" term to provide an intuition to easily understand the role of `Args...` in the snippet. I'll make it more clear in the answer that "pattern matching" is not happening on a technical level.