# Could class template deduction enable parameter packs in the middle of template?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

First, I want to say that I know that the following is not possible in C++17, I am more interested in whether it could be possible.

Function templates and class templates differ in the aspect that the first declaration is possible while the second is not:

```cpp
template<class ...Ts, class S>
void foo(S s);

template<class ...Ts, class S>
class bar;
```

In the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940875/parameter-pack-must-be-at-the-end-of-the-parameter-list-when-and-why) it is pointed out that this is because the compiler can deduce `S` from the function parameter, while it cannot do that for the class. So for the first code, it can differentiate between the `Ts` and `S` and it cannot in for the second code.

While I am still a bit unsure, why the compiler cannot deduce `S` by virtue of using the last template parameter, I see why the function case is clearly superior.

But the following does compile

```cpp
template<class ...Ts, class S>
void foo();
```

only one cannot call it in any way, since the compiler won't be able to deduce `S`. So theoretically, could one allow the declaration of `bar` to compile and outsource the error to whenever we want to use it? Then if we had no default constructor and a constructor like

```cpp
bar::bar(S s, Ts... ts); // Edit: Added Ts which are necessary as @Nicol Bolas. And I am aware that it is weird to turn them around here but not in the template.
```

we could deduce `S` from this, whenever we initialize an object of type `bar` (except for copying/moving, but then one just takes the same type as the object passed in).

So why is this not possible? Is it because `bar` is a type and one should be able to use it without instantiating an object of that type?

Comment: Asking *why is this not possible* is usually not a very good question. Theoretically we could make the language work in any way we want. There are probably a lot of good things missing in the language still, that's why they're still releasing new standards every 3 years.

Comment: Also, you should probably clarify what you mean by *outsource the error to whenever we want to use it*.

Comment: *Is it because bar is a type and one should be able to use it without instantiating an object of that type?* Yes.  If I want to make a `bar<int, double>` I couldn't since both `int` and `double` would become part of the parameter pack.

Comment: @super If we declare a function template that is unusable (see the second `foo` above), the declaration won't be a problem at all, but everytime you try to call it, the compiler will fail to deduce `S`. The same could be done for classes.

Comment: @n314159: "*we could deduce S from this*" No, you can't. That would require being able to deduce some of the parameters from a guide, while others were provided directly. That's not allowed. Class deduction guides (implicit or explicit) must provide all parameters to the template.

Comment: @n314159 I fail to see the point of allowing that if there is no way to instatiate the class. But it sounds perfectly possible to allow such a thing.

Comment: What problem would allowing this solve? You can just do this: `template<typename... Ts>
class bar { using S = std::tuple_element_t<sizeof...(Ts) - 1, std::tuple<Ts...>>; };`

Comment: @super It has not really a point^^ I find it just a bit weird that it is different for classes and functions. Actually I was a bit surprised that this was allowed for functions when I first found out.

Comment: @Kerndog73 That would certainly be a possibility to do the same thing (even if it is a bit annoying that `S` would still be part of `Ts...`, its mostly easier to set the `S` before the `Ts...`). But this is a purely theoretical question, I have no code where I would need that.